# EXCLUDE NODE FROM OUTPUT WHEN NULL

Tags: xml, xslt

Need to find a way to prevent an XML node from being output when there are no values populated in it.

This is the current part of XSLT I need to change:

```
<xsl:element name="CdtrAcct">
  <xsl:element name="Id">
   <xsl:element name="IBAN">
     <xsl:value-of select="Supplier/Iban"/>
   </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
```

After looking around I've tried changing to the following but it's not working:

```
<xsl:element name="CdtrAcct">
  <xsl:element name="Id">#
    <xsl:for-each select="CdtrAcct/Id">
  <xsl:if test="IBAN!= ''">
        <xsl:element name="IBAN">
          <xsl:value-of select="Supplier/Iban"/>
        </xsl:element>
  </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
```

i.e. If IBAN is blank then CdtrAcct/Id should not have an IBAN child node for that CdtrAcct/Id, but if the next CdtrAcct/Id has an IBAN then it should.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace this...

```
<xsl:if test="IBAN!= ''">
```

with this...

```
<xsl:if test="Supplier/Iban != ''">
```

As you should be testing the input node, not the output node. 
Also note, you don't need to use `xsl:element` here when you are dealing with static elements names, so you can just write this

```
<CdtrAcct>
  <Id>#
    <xsl:for-each select="CdtrAcct/Id">
      <xsl:if test="Supplier/Iban!= ''">
        <IBAN>
          <xsl:value-of select="Supplier/Iban"/>
        </IBAN>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Id>
</CdtrAcct>
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly.  I found that I also needed to exclude the ID node if IBAN was not populated so I moved the if test one level higher :)